# How can I access data sent via AJAX on Node JS server?

Tags: ajax, node.js

I would like to make a simple contact form for my website. I know how to use ajax to send data, but I don't know how to access it on the Node JS server.

If I were to send my data using this code:

```
var request=new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("POST","url");
request.send("{value:'10'}");
```

How can I access my value in the JSON object I pass to the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `request_.on("data", function(data_){});` to get my data.

If in my client JS I use `request.send("my data");`

I can access my data by adding a listener to the request_ object in my Node JS server function.

```
request_.on("data", function(data_){
  console.log(data_);// my data
}
```

I can then slice up my data any way I want to and use it how I see fit. No need for Express.

Here's my client function that is called when the submit button on my contact form is pressed:

```
function clickSubmit(event_) {
  var xmlhttprequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttprequest.open("POST", "contact");
  xmlhttprequest.send("email=" + html.email.value + "&name=" + html.name.value + "&message=" + html.message.value);
}
```

And here's my Node JS server function:

```
function handleRequest(request_, response_) {
  switch(request_.url) {
    case "/contact":
      request_.on("data", function(data_) {
        console.log("data: " + data_);// Outputs the string sent by AJAX.
      });
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Make sure you're accessing data_ as a string.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do this.

For example you could create an endpoint on your server e.g. with express http://expressjs.com/. It might look like this

```
router.post('/your/url', function(req, res, data) {
  var value = req.body.value;

  // do cool things with value

  res.send('cool');
});
```

You define a post endpoint which will handle your request. Using the request object you can access the JSON object from the request